# google cloud func simulator - limit functions to start?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, simulator

during development starting/restarting ALL the funcs in my app is slow, is there a way to limit the scope of functions? similar to how you can just deploy a subset with:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:token-tokenMetadata
```

I tried to do:

```
npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions:peopleai-createTune
```

but it will start *everything*

docs don't seem to mention:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we could test?

Comment: the above is relevant for ANY piece of code. the question is on how to start the emulator, not how to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not a feature. It sounds like an interesting idea though, so I recommend filing a request for it on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) of the project.